# Data intent is null in Android using universal links/applinks using react-native-app-auth

Tags: android, react-native, oauth, appauth, android-app-links

i am using `react-native-app-auth` for Authorization using okta.

I tried appSchemes and Applinks/universal links in both iOS and android. But android applinks giving me `[Error: Data intent is null]`. It is working fine with appScheme.
Redirection to the application is working, but something going wrong while capturing the auth response.
These are my configurations

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="myDomain.com"
        />
      </intent-filter>
```

**build.gradle:**

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
     appAuthRedirectScheme: 'myAppScheme',
 ]
```

AuthConfig:

```
{
        issuer: "https://dev-xxxxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default",
        clientId: '${MyClientId}',
        clientSecret: '${MyClientSecret}',
        redirectUrl: "${myDomain.com}",
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
      };
```

I suspect that i am missing some configuration in the Android setup while capturing the response of `authorize()` method. But i am unable to figure it.

I am seeing soo many references, but all are pointing to `appScheme`s but my issue is with `universal links/applinks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by wrapping the `intent-filter` in seperate `activity`. This is not mentioned anywhere in the document as i see.

```
    <activity
        android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity" 
        android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="myDomain.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```